# MongoDB network subnet lookup

Tags: mongodb

Let's say we have a collection of documents where each document represents a network subnet like this:

```
{'network':'10.0.0.0/24,'someattr':'aaa'}
{'network':'192.168.0.0/16','someattr':'bbb'}
{'network':'172.16.0.0/16','someattr':'ccc'}
```

Is there any way I can lookup a single ip address (e.g. '10.0.100.50') in the MongoDB collection and identify the subnet/document it belongs to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that IPs are just `int`s and subnet masks are just ranges of `int`s - they're displayed as they are so that humans can read them (among other reasons).  What I would do is add two additional fields to my MongoDB schema: `startAddr` and `endAddr`.  Represent them as `int`s and they will be the starting and ending addresses for your subnet.

Next, you can convert the IP to an `int` in your application. See [here](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/IP2Integer.jsp) for information on converting an IP to an integer, you didn't mention what language you're writing your application in so can't help you there.

Finally, query MongoDB on the following

```
db.collection.find({startAddr: {$lte: <ip>}, {endAddr: {$gte: <ip>}}})
```

You can also combine this new schema with some application level code to easily do things like find documents that have overlapping subnets if you need to do that.

Comment: We are doing this in production with Mongo for IP authentication of subscribers with arbitrary ranges.  This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Mason I really like your idea, but will this not lead to clutter in the documents?

Comment: It's a space vs time to look up vs complexity trade off.  In this case I think it's a relatively easy choice to stick a couple of extra attributes in there to make lookups easier in the future.  It's similar to looking up documents by month or year where the recommendation is to store each of those as their own attribute to increase ease of querying and allow indexing.  If disk space is the most important thing to you then you'll have to trade off pulling the subnets into your application layer and doing the comparisons there.